# Why does the GIF spec require at least 2-bits for the initial LZW code size?

Tags: algorithm, gif

I've been trying to figure out why the GIF89a spec requires that the initial LZW code size to be at least 2-bits, even when encoding 1-bit images (B&W).  In appendix F of the spec, it says the following:

> ESTABLISH CODE SIZE
>
> The first byte of the Compressed Data stream is a value indicating the minimum number of bits required to represent the set of actual pixel values. Normally this will be the same as the number of color bits. Because of some algorithmic constraints however, black & white images which have one color bit must be indicated as having a code size of 2.

I'm curious as to what these algorithmic constraints are.  What would possibly prevent the variant of LZW used in GIF from using a code size of 1? Was this just a limitation of the early encoders or decoders? Or is there some weird edge case that can manifest itself in with just the right combination of bits?  Or is there something completely different going on here?

Comment: I am not intimately familiar with that spec, but wouldn't some kind of EOF symbol also be required (in addition to 0 and 1)?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError yes, there are two additional codes reserved for CC and stop. But you don't include those when you write out the initial code size, since they are always there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the codes for `0` and `1`, you also have a `clear` code and an `end of information` code.

Quoting from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt):

> The output codes are of variable length, starting at +1 bits per
>   code, up to 12 bits per code. This defines a maximum code value of 4095
>   (0xFFF). Whenever the LZW code value would exceed the current code length, the
>   code length is increased by one.

If you start with a code size of 1, the code size needs to be increased immediately by this rule.

Comment: Yes, but that's true no matter what the color depth. But 1-bit and 2-bit colors both should have the same initial code size, which means that there will be one bit wasted for each code in the 1-bit color depth case.

Comment: @DennisMunsie the codes always start at n+1 bits. For n=1, the table starts out full right from the start, with all 4 possible values taken: `0`, `1`, `clear`, `EOI`. For any other value of `n` the table does *not* start out full - for n=2 you use 6 of 8, for n=3 you use 10 of 16, etc.

Comment: I think between yours and @EgorSkriptunoff's answer, there is enough for me to say this has been answered.  Since I can only mark one answer as "correct", I'm going to mark this one correct since it looks like you answered it first.  Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 1):

This limitation gets rid of one `if` in implementation (with codesize==1 the first vocabulary phrase code would have width==codesize+2, in all other cases width==codesize+1).
The drawback is very small decreasing in compression ratio for 2-color pictures.

Comment: But the `clear` code always requires n+1 bits by definition, I don't see how it would be different for the 1-bit case.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Sorry, fixed.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I think you might have something here. With a 1-bit color table, the first added entry will automatically expand the width, negating any savings from using a smaller width. In fact, it would mean the most you could save is just 1 bit, since only the first pixel would be encoded with the smaller code size. Having this rule probably made the implementation of decoders slightly easier, especially on the machines of 1987 when GIF was first being implemented.